# Curl won't accept -X parameter

Tags: curl, bitbucket-server

Running this curl command:

```
curl -u user:pass -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/fw/repos
```

fails with:

`bash: -X: command not found
   $ curl: no URL specified!`

This command worked before, so I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a spcial character in you username or, more probably, in the password. Try using single quotes around the credentials, like so:

```
curl -u 'user:pass' -X POST -H "Content-Type: applicat.....
```